# How to Dynamically highlight some words in html format

Tags: java, highlight

I have a List that includes lots of keywords, and I have another List that includes lots of text in HTML format.

I want to dynamically highlight my keywords wherever they come up in the text.

What is the best way to do this job in java?

Answer (score 0):

Apply some css to your html. Use jsoup framework for manipulation of your html list.

Your question is very broad, add some more details for a better answer.